# Page content loading issue using Walker_Nav_Menu

Tags: menus, walker

At each page refresh, the page loads in steps, first the header with main menu and then after 1 second, the page loads the rest of content.

I use the following code to display the a mega menu on my theme:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => 'main-nav',
    'fallback_cb'     => 'my_fallback_menu',
    'theme_location'  => 'main-menu',
    'walker'          => new My_Menu_Walker() // mega menu
    )
);
```

And below is the code used for My_Menu_Walker() in a separate file:

```
<?php

if ( ! class_exists( 'My_Menu_Walker', false ) ) {

    class My_Menu_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

// add main/sub classes to li's and links
        public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
            $indent = ( $depth > 0 ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent

            // depth dependent classes
            $depth_classes = array(
                ( $depth == 0 ? 'main-menu-item' : 'sub-menu-item' ),
                ( $depth >=2 ? 'sub-sub-menu-item' : '' ),
                ( $depth % 2 ? 'menu-item-odd' : 'menu-item-even' ),
                'menu-item-depth-' . $depth
                );
            $depth_class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', $depth_classes ) );

            // passed classes
            $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
            $class_names = esc_attr( implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) ) );

            // build html
            $output .= $indent . '<li id="nav-menu-item-'. $item->ID . '" class="' . $depth_class_names . ' ' . $class_names . '">';

            // link attributes
            $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
            $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
            $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
            $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
            $attributes .= ' class="menu-link ' . ( $depth > 0 ? 'sub-menu-link' : 'main-menu-link' ) . '"';


            $item_output = sprintf( '%1$s<a%2$s>%3$s%4$s%5$s</a>%6$s',
                $args->before,
                $attributes,
                $args->link_before,
                apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ),
                $args->link_after,
                $args->after
                );

            // add menu for categories
            if ( $depth == 0 && $item->object == 'category' ) {
                $item_output .= '<div class="sub-menu-box">';
            }

            // build html
            $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
        }

        function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_object_id = 0 ) {
            global $wp_query;
            global $post;

            // build html for menu with categories
            if ( $depth == 0 && $item->object == 'category' ) {
                $cat = $item->object_id;
                ob_start();
                ?>
                <ul class="sub-menu-posts">
                    <div class="td-mega-ul">
                        <?php
                        $post_args = array( 'numberposts' => 3, 'offset'=> 0, 'category' => $cat );
                        $menuposts = get_posts( $post_args );
                        foreach( $menuposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
                        echo '<li class="grid col-340">';
                        get_template_part( 'parts/mega-menu', get_post_format() );
                        echo '</li>';
                        endforeach;
                        wp_reset_postdata();
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </ul>

                <?php
                $output .= ob_get_clean();
                $output .= "</div>\n";
            }

            $output .= "</li>\n";
        }

        // add classes to ul sub-menus
        public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
            // depth dependent classes
            $indent = ( $depth > 0  ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '' ); // code indent
            $display_depth = ( $depth + 1); // because it counts the first submenu as 0
            $classes = array(
                'sub-menu',
                ( $display_depth % 2  ? 'menu-odd' : 'menu-even' ),
                ( $display_depth >=2 ? 'sub-sub-menu' : '' ),
                'menu-depth-' . $display_depth
                );
            $class_names = implode( ' ', $classes );

            // build html
            $output .= "\n" . $indent . '<ul class="' . $class_names . '">' . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the template part code:

```
<div class="td-mega-content">
    <article class="post-<?php the_ID(); ?> td-mega-posts">

        <?php if ( '' != get_the_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
        <div class="mega-post-thumbnail">
            <a class="module-image" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'module-1' ); ?>
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="td-mega-posts-inner">

        <h3 class="entry-title">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
            </a>
        </h3>

        <div class="post-meta">
            <?php echo esc_attr( get_the_time('F j, Y') ); ?>
        </div>

    </div><?php // end of .td-mega-posts-inner ?>

</article>

</div><?php // end of .td-mega-content ?>
```

Important: the problem only occurs using the `'walker' => new My Menu Walker()` in the `wp_nav_menu` code that shows the menu.

What can be wrong that causes this loading page issue?

Comment: In your nav walker you are quering posts and loading a template part to show them. You have not posted it but I think the problem can be there. If that template part loads heavy content, for example large images or high number of them, it is possible that you experiment waiting times until the content of the menu is loaded and the browser can continue making new requests and loading content. You have to prioritize visible and above the fold content for a better user experience. Maybe you can load the mega menu via ajax after document is fully loaded.

Comment: Thanks @cybmeta but even I comment out the template part line the issue is still there. However, I just notice that if I comment out the entire foreach&endforeach code part, the issue is gone. Any thoughts?

Comment: I just posted the template part code. See updated question content. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know. If the content loaded by the template part is not causing the problem I can not image a single reason to be difference in download proccess between remove the template part or the entire foreach loop beacuse the only thing the foreach loop seems to do is loading the template par.